# Update Servlet API in Google App Engine Backend

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, servlets

I'm developing an application backend using Google App Engine. The backend is written in Java in Android Studio.
I'm trying to implementing HttpServlet that receives multipart request with image, and I read I need the Servlet API 3.0 or grater, and the app engine comes with 2.5. I add the next compile in the backend module's gradle file dependencies:

```
compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
```

and also change the web.xml to:

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
```

I deployed it to the app engine (No errors) and all the servlets work fine, except the one I used the 3.0 new feature

```
for(Part part : req.getParts())
        log("name : " + part.getName() + ", ContentType : " + part.getContentType());
```

The exception shown in the backend:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParts()Ljava/util/Collection;
```

Did I forgot something in the API updating process?
Thanks :)

Comment: as you mentioned _app engine comes with 2.5_, so you cannot use 3.0 features, it doesn't exists there

Comment: @IgorArtamonov So what else can I do to process the multipart request?

Comment: Servlet Api 2.5 is enough for multipart uploads (remember there was file uploads in web long before 3.0 was introduced). You can try other libs, like Apache Commons FileUpload for example. Also, for App Engine, it's strongly recommended to use native services such as Blobstore for upload and Storage for actual storage, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob